Are questions about economic impact allowed at all?
There have been a few questions about how Bitcoin can effect the economy:

Effect on economy if Bitcoin was widely adopted
Could Bitcoin work as a world currency?
Can the price of Bitcoin ever be stable to the USD?

And they all have close votes or are closed.
When asking economic questions, what should be avoided?

One thing to avoid is a question that's a good debate starter. If there's equal and valid arguments on both sides of an issue, a question will just get "Yes it is" and "No it isn't" replies that will be argumentative and subjective.

While it's difficult to avoid politically charged questions (or answers) with a technology as potentially disruptive as Bitcoin, economics is at the core of the Bitcoin concept so economic questions are almost certainly on-topic so long as they reference Bitcoin in some regard. Those questions all have close votes or are closed because they are unanswerable, at least at the present time. In short, we're not downvoting or closing them because they're off-topic or politically charged, but because they aren't answers and they're likely to incite argument.

One way of phrasing these types of questions would be something like,
"When people say that hoarding bitcoins is bad, what set of assumptions are they using?"
That avoids the Is X good? type questions which are a debate and instead just asks for what the arguments are for one particular side of an argument and what the assumptions people making those arguments are using.
